# Get the highest number of a list using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a dict like this :

```
my_dict = {
    "['000A']":
        ['1653418_a0001b001.jpg',
         '2132018_a0002b002.jpg',
         '4789562_a0001b003.jpg',
         '8469844_a0009b004.jpg',
         '4815099_a0004b000.jpg',
         '9085654_a0001b001.jpg',
         '9742212_a0007b002.jpg',
         '1325874_a0002b009.jpg',
         '1474856_a0090f014.jpg']
    ,
    "['000B']":
        ['1653418_a0001b001.jpg',
         '2132018_a0002b002.jpg',
         '4789562_a0001b003.jpg',
         '8469844_a0009b004.jpg',
         '4815099_a0004b000.jpg',
         '9085654_a0001b001.jpg',
         '9742212_a0007b002.jpg',
         '1325874_a0002b009.jpg',
         '123456_a0090f020.jpg']
}
```

And I want to find  the highest number following the "b" for each keys of the dict

```
for key, value in my_dict
    number = re.findall('\d+', string)
    #convert it into integer
    number = map(int, number)
    print("Max_value:",max(number))
```

It doesn't work because then it would find the value at the begining of the string. I was thinking then to use a `.endswith(("....."))`

But still, I don't know how to formulate it to match my need, which would be a pattern that after `'b'` matches 4 numbers or 4 number followed by `'.jpg'` or even `endwith` `'b'` + 4 numbers and `'.jpg'`
but also I would like the code to find what number is the highest bXXXX and then return :

```
{"['000A']": '1474856_a0090f014.jpg', "['000B']": '123456_a0090f020.jpg'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it can appear both "b" or "f".

```
output_dict = {}
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    output_dict[key] = sorted(value, key=lambda x: int(re.match(".*[bf](\d+)\.jpg", x).groups()[0]))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 numbers after the `b` or `f`. If there can be more variations of lowercase chars, you can match a single lowercase char with `[a-z]` If there can be a variation of digits, you can match 1 or more using `\d+` or match 3 or more using `\d{3,}`

Then you could match`.jpg` at the end of the string.

If there is a match, get the capture group 1 value and convert it to an int and use that to sort on.

After the sorting, get the first item from the list (assuming there are no empty lists)

```
import re

my_dict = {
    "['000A']":
        ['1653418_a0001b001.jpg',
         '4789562_a0001b003.jpg',
         '8469844_a0009b004.jpg',
         '4815099_a0004b000.jpg',
         '1474856_a0090f014.jpg',
         '9085654_a0001b001.jpg',
         '9742212_a0007b002.jpg',
         '1325874_a0002b009.jpg']
    ,
    "['000B']":
        ['1653418_a0001b001.jpg',
         '2132018_a0002b002.jpg',
         '4789562_a0001b003.jpg',
         '8469844_a0009b004.jpg',
         '4815099_a0004b000.jpg',
         '9085654_a0001b001.jpg',
         '9742212_a0007b002.jpg',
         '123456_a0090f020.jpg',
         '1325874_a0002b009.jpg']
}

dct_highest_number = {}

for key, value in my_dict.items():
    dct_highest_number[key] = sorted(
        value,
        key=lambda x: [int(m.group(1)) for m in [re.search(r"[a-z](\d+)\.jpg$", x)] if m],
        reverse=True
    )[0]

print(dct_highest_number)
```

Output

```
{"['000A']": '1474856_a0090f014.jpg', "['000B']": '123456_a0090f020.jpg'}
```